# «...и(,) когда он приехал на покос, косцы шли уже по второму ряду»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Из "Анны Карениной":

> На другое утро Константин Левин встал раньше обыкновенного, но хозяйственные распоряжения задержали его, **и когда** он приехал на покос, косцы шли уже по второму ряду.

Почему после "и" нет запятой? Можно ли поставить ее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятой нет, потому что союз и присоединяет не главное предложение, а всё сложноподчинённое:

*[На другое утро Константин Левин встал раньше обыкновенного], но [хозяйственные распоряжения задержали его], и { (когда он приехал на покос), [косцы шли уже по второму ряду]}.*

Запятая возможна, но смысл чуть изменится, союз и будет присоединять главное предложение:

*[На другое утро Константин Левин встал раньше обыкновенного], но [хозяйственные распоряжения задержали его], и, (когда он приехал на покос), [косцы шли уже по второму ряду].* Акцент сместился на действия косцов, а не Левина: Левин встал раньше, распоряжения задержали его, и косцы шли по второму кругу. У Толстого же акцент на опоздании Левина.

Кстати, на некоторых сайтах эта запятая есть - видимо, корректоры поработали, но подошли к работе формально: если придаточное свободно вынимается, нет продолжения подчинительного союза когда...**то**, запятая между сочинительным и подчинительным союзом ставится. При работе с текстами таких мастеров слова, как Толстой, нужно быть внимательным к смыслу текста.