# Ставится ли запятая перед тире?

Tags: запятые, тире

**Не обязательно, но, если найду(,) — напишу.**

Да, тут можно поставить просто запятую, но мне интересен именно с тире, где ставится пауза. По ответу на этот вопрос [Нужна ли запятая перед тире в следующих предложениях?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474472/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85) выходит, что нужна.
А также:

**Что это было(,) — неизвестно**;

**Но то, где это было(,) — неизвестно**.

Все так же, мне интересен случай именно с тире.

В первом случае *что* — это не союзное слово, а подлежащее, так что это не придаточное, и, следовательно, запятая не ставится. Это так?

Во втором случае есть подлежащее — это *то*, союзное слово — *где*, так что если слушаться этот ответ по этой же ссылке, то запятая нужна.

Не пишите, что можно не усложнять и поменять предложения, чтоб не париться. Мне интересны именно эти случаи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не обязательно, но, если найду, — напишу.

На мой взгляд, запятая нужна. Она закрывает придаточное предложение. Тире интонационное, оно показывает, что в этом месте нужно сделать паузу.

Мне кажется, если бы не было слова "но" или если бы не было запятой после "но", то можно было бы обойтись одним тире (см. следующий пример; также см. в [этом вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/460015/192807) пример непостановки запятой после сочинительного союза).

> Что это было — неизвестно.

Запятая не нужна, тире заменяет запятую. *Что это было* — придаточное предложение, его можно поставить в конец: *Неизвестно, что это было*. [Тема в справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142).

> Но то, где это было, — неизвестно.

Запятая нужна, так как закрывает придаточное предложение. Тире стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым ("то" и "неизвестно" соответственно).

Answer (score 3):

Можно записать так: ***Не обязательно, но если найду — напишу.***

1. Тире ставится в СПП с придаточным изъяснительным по [правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142)

Тире ставится **для интонационного отделения** главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части **предшествует**: 1) придаточная **изъяснительная**: Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять (Г.); Как рассказывал учитель — долго слушал у окна я (Пл.).

Интонационное отделение — это использование **тире вместо запятой** для обозначения увеличенной паузы.

2. СПП можно рассматривать как **единую конструкцию**, стоящую после союза НО. Такая графика выглядит лучше, лишние запятые здесь ни к чему.

Сравнить: Не обязательно, но **в случае находки** — напишу.

3. ***Что это было** — неизвестно.* **СПП** с придаточным изъяснительным.

*Но то, **где это было**, — неизвестно.*  Сравнить: Но то неизвестно, где это было. Здесь местоименная связь, другой случай.